# Elasticsearch 2.0 NoClassDefFoundError for JsonXContentGenerator

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to update my elasticsearch java client api version from 1.4.2 to 2.0.0. I am using java 1.8 .I use this code:

```
   XContentBuilder builder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
```

It used to work in 1.4.2 but I get this exception in 2.0.0:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContentGenerator
   at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContent.newXContentGenerator(JsonXContent.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
   at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContent.createGenerator(JsonXContent.java:74) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
   at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContent.createGenerator(JsonXContent.java:80) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
   at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.<init>(XContentBuilder.java:112) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
   at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.<init>(XContentBuilder.java:102) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
   at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder.builder(XContentBuilder.java:80) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
   at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.json.JsonXContent.contentBuilder(JsonXContent.java:40) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
   at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.contentBuilder(XContentFactory.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
   at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory.jsonBuilder(XContentFactory.java:49) ~[elasticsearch-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
```

In pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
       <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason is I didnt have com.fasterxml.jackson.core in my dependency list, so this was causing

```
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultIndenter
```

I added this into my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

And problem solved!