# I am trying to develop web services REST application.I have a no idea how to solve following error

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jsp

**My code is**

```
package com.binod.formvalidation;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView; 
import com.binod.formvalidation.Entity.Student;

@Controller
public class FormValidationController {
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/students", method=RequestMethod.GET)

public ArrayList<Student> getStudent(){

    Student student=new Student();
    student.setFirstName("Binod");
    Student student1=new Student();
    student1.setFirstName("Ram");
    Student student2=new Student();
    student2.setFirstName("Bhim");

    ArrayList<Student> arrayList=new ArrayList<Student>();
    arrayList.add(student);
    arrayList.add(student1);
    arrayList.add(student2);
    return arrayList;

}
}
```

**Student.java**

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import com.binod.formvalidation.IsValidHobby;
import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

public class Student {
    @Size(min=4,max=9)
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull
    private int rollNo;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }

    public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }

}
```

**SpringFormValidation-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                 
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
  xsi:schemaLocation=
  "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   **strong text**http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd"> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.binod.formvalidation" / <mvc:annotation-driven />     
<mvc:interceptors>
<mvc:interceptor>
<mvc:mapping path="/form.html"/>  
<bean class="com.binod.formvalidation.inteceptor.DayOfWeekInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors> 
<bean id="viewResolver"         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
         <property name="prefix">
             <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
         </property>
         <property name="suffix">
             <value>.jsp</value>
          </property>
</bean> 
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/studentMessage" />
</bean>
</bean>
```

**OutPut is**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultIndenter
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.init(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:97)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:90)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:66)
    org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:57)
    org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:61)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.<init>(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:182)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1108)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1060)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1366)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have no idea how to solve that error.I am a beginner in spring and web services. when i add 
    `jackson-annotations-2.0.0.jar,jackson-core-2.0.0.jar,jackson-databind-2.0.0.jar` three `jar` in lib folder it gives above error.How to solve above error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668694/elasticsearch-2-0-noclassdeffounderror-for-jsonxcontentgenerator

Comment: include jackson dependency

Comment: @suraj i am not use a maven.i have no idea please give me detail information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove `jackson-core-2.0.0.jar` from your lib directory and download [this](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.5.0/jackson-core-2.5.0.jar) jar file to lib directory.

Comment: above problem solve but java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList error occured.how to solve that error.

Comment: If this has solved the above mentioned problem, accept the answer and open up a new thread with the stacktrace.

Comment: solve that error also i download jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar and jackson-annotations-2.8.8.jar added to the lib directory

Answer (score 1):

Class `DefaultIndenter` is presented in jackson-core-**2.5.0** (the version you have is 2.0.0). So make sure you use the right lib version.

Answer (score 1):

DefaultIndenter class is appended Since: v2.5 to com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util package. So you shuould change jackson-core-2.0.0.jar with jackson-core-2.5.0.jar

for more detail look at offical web site :https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultIndenter.html

Answer (score 1):

The class DefaultIndenter was added in 2.5.0 version, upgrade your dependency to this version and it will work. More details take a look here:

https://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/compat_report/jackson-core/2.4.6/2.5.0/c8da9/src_compat_report.html